# How to change a combobox's context on another combobox's selection change event?

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a static datastore named books. Every book has a key field that specifies its category like crime, fiction etc. and name of the book.

And on the ui I have two comboboxes. One of them is to select the category and the other one for the list of books that matches with the selected category. The question is how to change the context of the booklist combobox by the selected category (in my datastore it is named key).

Any example appriciated.

Comment: write your extjs version please

Comment: http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/examples/kitchensink/#binding-combo-chaining

Comment: Sorry I forget to write it @IgorSemin. It is 4.0.7

Comment: @EvanTrimboli thanks for the answer but I want to do it by adding a listener: "When a value is selected change the context of the second combobox".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice example:

```
listeners : {
                                'select' : function(ClearableComboBox)
                                {
                                    var bookCat = ClearableComboBox.getValue();
                                    var cmbxCat = Ext.getCmp('category');
                                    if(bookCat == '1'){ 
                                        ds = Ext.create('store.CrimeDS');
                                    } else if(bookCat == '2'){ 
                                        ds = Ext.create('store.FictionDS');
                                    } else ..                           
                                    cmbxCat.bindStore(ds);
                                }
                            }
```